# Multiple monitors on/off switch

Tags: hardware-rec

Im fairly new to SU , but not to SO.

As a coder I use 3 external monitors which are connected to my docking station, and I was wondering
if there's anything on the market that I can get to switch all of them on and off at once?

So when i go to sleep at night i would have to turn them one by one ('first world problems' anyone?)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just plug all three monitors into a regular power strip?

Comment: Probably turning off all of'em at once is not an issue as you may use any switched power strip. I think the problem is turning them on by just one action - is that right?

Comment: @ScottRhee :If switch OFF at once is not an issue then what is the issue with powering ON?. what do you mean by your comment?

Comment: @Pavel 'PK' Kaminsky : Are you looking for [this](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=s9_dnav_bw_ir03_s?node=228013,!468240,495266,495314&field-feature_keywords_two_browse-bin=5424273011&page=1&bbn=495314&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=1ZBYTRM91Q7DBWVX3Y7N&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1387566602&pf_rd_i=495314) kind of products or not?

Comment: @Renju: It's because some monitors may not turn on until manually pushing the power button on them. It depends on their hardware design. So, to achieve the goal, this should be tested first prior to buying a strip.

Comment: @ScottRhee: Good catch. +1 for that.

Comment: ScottRhee - absolutely not.
@RenjuChandranchingath - right on spot, this is an issue.

also why the downvotes?

Comment: @Pavel 'PK' Kaminsky: I ain't  down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a [powerstrip](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=s9_dnav_bw_ir03_s?node=228013,!468240,495266,495314&field-feature_keywords_two_browse-bin=5424273011&page=1&bbn=495314&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=1ZBYTRM91Q7DBWVX3Y7N&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1387566602&pf_rd_i=495314) to power up all your monitors.